# Clickable phone hyperlink in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a hyperlink with a phone in Google Sheets so that when I click on it, I can make a call (I'm trying to use Facetime in MacOS). The following works when I access the Google Sheet from an iOS device.

=HYPERLINK("https://call.ctrlq.org/" &A1, A1)  //where A1 is the cell with a phone number

However, when open it in Chrome, I just get a page showing "Redirecting you to [https://call.ctrlq.org/phone-number"](https://call.ctrlq.org/phone-number%22). When I open the link in Safari, I get "This website has been blocked from automatically starting a call." and When I allow the call, nothing happens.

I also tried to use =HYPERLINK("tel:123456789, "Call Me") and that one doesn't even create a hyperlink in Google Sheets.